# From Angular to React - how to decouple business logic from components?

Tags: angular, reactjs, redux

Main problem for people that come from Angular is how to properly decouple business logic from presentation. I don't want it to be inside of component, so in Angular we simply created service layer, where we stored our logic, and accessed those services via dependency injection.

Since react is functional programming, I am wondering what are the best practices for building and decoupling logic from views (components)?

Let's say I have authentication service, for which I use OIDC to authenticate against Identity Server. I have one class and multiple functions inside in Angular.

```
export class LoginComponent{
_authService: AuthService;
constructor(){authService: AuthService}

login():void {
let result= _authService.login("user", "password);
}
}
```

How can I decouple logic in React? Let's say I had 10 methods in authService, making quite huge class, or if I segregate to smaller classes, how to link all those? I read about HOC pattern, container pattern and redux(actions and dispatchers) and classic module exporting and storing functions inside(aka helpers). I am not really sure if helpers would be good practice.

Is there standard or is here a mix of all?

I mostly see tutorials on internet where there is just basic syntax, and not real structuring of app and decoupling.

Comment: Angular is a full MVC framework. Hence it is in charge of handling your bussiness logic too. This is not the case for React which is a pure View framework.
Hence it is in charge of rendering components, and has no requirements or assumptions of how your model is maintained. Usually people use Redux for the Model and Controller part. Usually you would create "dumb" components, which only renders views based on props. Then you can use Redux or whatever else to provide the data to the components.

Comment: The same goes with your methods. Simply pass them down as props. Then your component is only responsible of invoking the function, however what happens when it is invoked, is based on which props you pass to it. This could for instance be a dispatch of a redux action ;-)

Answer (score 5):

First of all angular is (at least more than react) a MVC framework, which is why it provides tools for handling both views and logic. React is a pure 'View' framework, hence it makes no assumption on how your business logic works, nor does it provide any tools for it. In order to handle your model you could use something like [redux](https://redux.js.org/) or [mobx](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx), or you could build your own architecture which usually would follow the [flux pattern](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html). While for instance Redux is based on concepts from functional programming, React is not purely functional and does not enforce any functional style. However i do recommend using the functional programming concepts!

Now the 'best practices' is obviously very opinionated, and does depend a lot on the scale of your application. So i think that **you will find no single answer** on what the "right" way to do it is.

Personally i like to use Redux for my state management (logic) which is the MC part you are not getting from React. If you put all application state in Redux, and modify it by dispatching actions, then your components does never have to know about anything in your business logic. This is where the *container pattern* might be useful. From this you get the following

- **Smart components** know about and interact with redux. Hence they can access your model state, and dispatch actions on the model.
- **Dumb components** know nothing about your model state. They should be purely rendered based on the props you pass to it!

If you follow the container pattern strictly you will experience that view debugging becomes much easier, since every component is strictly rendered based on the props you pass to it. Hence this will give you the following separation of components and logic.

You business logic <-> Smart components <-> Dumb components

**Now here you can have some example code**

Let us create some very simple "logic"

```
class logic  {      
  constructor(value) {
    this.importantVariable = value;
  }

  importantOperation = () => new logic(this.importantVariable + 1);
}
```

Next let us create a smart component which is in charge of parsing the logic down to the dumb components

```
class SomeSmartComponent extends React.Component {      
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {logic: new logic(1)};
  }

  logicOperation = () => this.setState({logic: this.state.logic.importantOperation()});

  render() {
    return (
      <SomeDumbComponent 
        importantLogicVariable={this.state.logic.importantVariable}
        onClick={this.logicOperation}/>
    );
  }
}
```

Finally we can create a dumb component which renders our logic based on the props we pass it

```
class SomeDumbComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>I know nothing about the application state</div>
        <div>However i have a prop with value: <b>{this.props.importantLogicVariable}</b></div>
        <div>And i can invoke actions by a button press</div>
        <button 
          type="button"
          onClick={this.props.onClick}>
          Do something
        </button>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Notice that the dumb component has no knowledge of our business logic. It simply displays some info we pass to it. Even the logic function we invoke is transparent to the dumb component, it simply know that when the button is clicked, it should invoke "something". What that thing is, is purely based on the function we pass down as a prop.

You can also [see it in action here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VdarXZ)